# Can segmentation algorithms like U_Net segment dents in bullets?

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have a dataset of images of bullets. These bullets are to be classified as OK and Not-OK based on the segmentation of defects on the surface of bullets and any dents in the body of bullets.

I am using the U-Net segmentation algorithm. This is segmenting the surface defects well as it has a specific texture and gray color.

But I am also told to segment dents in the body of the bullet.

My algorithm is segmenting the surface defects well but is not able to segment dents on the body.

My question is, is it possible for U-Net to also predict the dents, do I need to further train the network, as a dent is a defect in the body and not the surface, it has a defective shape and not texture or color?

Or it is not possible for segmentation algos to predict and segment dents?

Comment: if you have data that also segments those, i don't see why not